# None returned in processing POST form

Tags: django, django-forms

I am working on a web page that takes a set of song titles and artist names, and finds the lyrics for the songs.

I have a minimal `search` page with a `POST` form and a submit button.

```
def search(request):
    formset = modelformset_factory(Song, fields=('title', 'artist', 'song_pk'))
    return render(request, 'lyricfind/search.html', {'formset': formset})
```

for the view, and

```
<form method="post" action="/results/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

for the template.

However, when I enter data in the text input fields and click the submit button, an error

```
The view lyricfind.views.results didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

is thrown.

I do not see what causes this error.

I wasn't sure about how I should write my view, so the view could be the cause.

```
def results(request):
    SongFormSet = modelformset_factory(Song)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = SongFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('lyricfind/results.html', {'formset': formset}))

    return render(request, 'lyricfind/search.html', {'formset': formset})
```

The template, `results.html`, just contains some plain text.

I believe urls are properly configured

```
url(r'^', include('lyricfind.urls', namespace='lyricfind')),
```

and then in `lyricfind.urls`,

```
url(r'^$', views.search, name='search'),
url(r'^results/$', views.results, name='results'),
```

Comment: I would bet you have an error in HttpResponseRedirect, within the reverse that likely returns None on error (because lyricfind/results.html is not a URL defined in urls.py.  reverse needs either 'search' or 'results', one of your URLs that are defined.  why using Redirect/Reverse here anyways?

Answer (score -1):

try changing code to this:

```
def results(request):
    SongFormSet = modelformset_factory(Song)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = SongFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            # SAVE or Process Data Then:
            return redirect('/some-save-confirmation-result-page')
            # or if your doing just a search, should use GET and can return a rendered template.

    return render(request, 'lyricfind/search.html', {'formset': formset})
```

Comment: but in an example that I saw, it used HttpResponseRedirect. Why is it not proper in my case? By the way it worked.

Comment: perhaps the redirect would have worked. but i dont see why you would in this case. your trying to render a different template if you have results. so why redirect? just render the template.

Comment: This is wrong. You should always redirect after a successful post. However you redirect to a URL, not a template. If you just want a search form, you should use GET, not POST.

Comment: you dont have to redirect @Danielle. technically he shouldnt be posting but using get

Comment: But should I use GET? I am going to access the submitted fields and pass them to instantiate a new `Song` object, and some others. Isn't this considered modifying the database and shouldn't the data be submitted using POST?

Comment: if your saving to the database, you should do that then redirect to a new page; if following @DanielRoseman strict RESTful like methodology.  I've updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: @DanielRoseman down voting (marking my answer as UN-useful) is not in the spirit of this site; I not only answered his question, but solved his problem.  It may not match your sense of right/wrong; but that is what the comment section is for.  Voting is if I've completely missed the format/spirit of the site.